# Maven 2.2 seems to fail during compilation on OSX 10.10

Tags: java, macos, maven-2, build-process, osx-yosemite

We have a big maven project which compiles just fine on linux(ubuntu) machines.

We are using JDK 1.7.0_71

However, trying to build it(`mvn clean install`) on osx 10.10.1 on some modules in the project, maven fails with the following exception message:

any ideas??

```
[ERROR] FATAL ERROR
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] 9728
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Trace
java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 9728
    at hidden.org.codehaus.plexus.util.xml.pull.MXParser.parsePI(MXParser.java:2470)
    at hidden.org.codehaus.plexus.util.xml.pull.MXParser.parseEpilog(MXParser.java:1575)
    at hidden.org.codehaus.plexus.util.xml.pull.MXParser.nextImpl(MXParser.java:1405)
    at hidden.org.codehaus.plexus.util.xml.pull.MXParser.next(MXParser.java:1105)
    at org.apache.maven.model.io.xpp3.MavenXpp3Reader.parseModel(MavenXpp3Reader.java:2133)
    at org.apache.maven.model.io.xpp3.MavenXpp3Reader.read(MavenXpp3Reader.java:3912)
    at org.apache.maven.project.DefaultMavenProjectBuilder.readModel(DefaultMavenProjectBuilder.java:1606)
    at org.apache.maven.project.DefaultMavenProjectBuilder.readModel(DefaultMavenProjectBuilder.java:1571)
    at org.apache.maven.project.DefaultMavenProjectBuilder.findModelFromRepository(DefaultMavenProjectBuilder.java:562)
    at org.apache.maven.project.DefaultMavenProjectBuilder.buildFromRepository(DefaultMavenProjectBuilder.java:251)
    at org.apache.maven.project.artifact.MavenMetadataSource.retrieveRelocatedProject(MavenMetadataSource.java:163)
    at org.apache.maven.project.artifact.MavenMetadataSource.retrieveRelocatedArtifact(MavenMetadataSource.java:94)
    at org.apache.maven.artifact.resolver.DefaultArtifactCollector.recurse(DefaultArtifactCollector.java:387)
    at org.apache.maven.artifact.resolver.DefaultArtifactCollector.recurse(DefaultArtifactCollector.java:435)
    at org.apache.maven.artifact.resolver.DefaultArtifactCollector.collect(DefaultArtifactCollector.java:74)
    at org.apache.maven.artifact.resolver.DefaultArtifactResolver.resolveTransitively(DefaultArtifactResolver.java:316)
    at org.apache.maven.artifact.resolver.DefaultArtifactResolver.resolveTransitively(DefaultArtifactResolver.java:304)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultPluginManager.resolveTransitiveDependencies(DefaultPluginManager.java:1499)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultPluginManager.java:442)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.DefaultLifecycleExecutor.executeGoals(DefaultLifecycleExecutor.java:694)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.DefaultLifecycleExecutor.executeGoalWithLifecycle(DefaultLifecycleExecutor.java:556)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.DefaultLifecycleExecutor.executeGoal(DefaultLifecycleExecutor.java:535)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.DefaultLifecycleExecutor.executeGoalAndHandleFailures(DefaultLifecycleExecutor.java:387)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.DefaultLifecycleExecutor.executeTaskSegments(DefaultLifecycleExecutor.java:348)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.DefaultLifecycleExecutor.execute(DefaultLifecycleExecutor.java:180)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:328)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:138)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:362)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.compat.CompatibleMain.main(CompatibleMain.java:60)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.codehaus.classworlds.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:315)
    at org.codehaus.classworlds.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:255)
    at org.codehaus.classworlds.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:430)
    at org.codehaus.classworlds.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:375)
```

Comment: Use a newer version of maven. Version 2.x is positively archaic and has been [eol'ed](http://maven.apache.org/maven-2.x-eol.html).

Comment: Thanks, this is a very big and old project, we tried that, compiling with maven 3 creates issues which effects class loading that eventually fail the services from starting. I am for one not even sure it will solve this problem let alone create a whole new set of problems.

Comment: Are you using the `MAVEN_OPTS` environment variable to increase the JVM memory?

Comment: Yes, I increased the memory to 1M and it is still happening

Comment: 1M is tiny - you sure it should not be 1024M?

Comment: First build on linux with a newer maven version like Maven 3.1.1 and afterwards try the same on Mac OS...

Comment: I gave up, moved to maven 3 which does not have this problem